# Mouse slows down and wireless receiver message

Tags: security, mouse

My mouse suddenly slowed down. Then I must wait about a minute so that it will get back to its normal speed, then after using about 10 seconds it slows down again. I turned my computer off and on, detached and attached usb of mouse but result is the same

why did this happen and whata can I do to fix?

at the same minute that my mouse first slowed down, I saw a message in the lower right of my screen, it said "we are installing a wireless receiver" or something like that, I forgot exact wording but I do remember it said wireless receiver. As if one of those windows messages my computer gives me sometimes. What wireless receiver? Can these two things be related, and why did this happen , is someone doing something to my computer remotely?

I use Windows 10

Never experienced such thing before

Answer (score 0):

duh.... I changed the mouse battery and it work again....

but how about the wireless receiver message? where did it come from?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/989588)

Comment: @DaveM that was OP and it was, literally, the answer to the question.